# Wit.ai How to set quick replies from action?

Tags: wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

I am very new to bot development. I am playing wit.ai with facebook messanger. How do we set `quick replies` from `action`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
if quick_replies:
    data['message']['quick_replies'] =[{'content_type': 'text', 'title': qr, 'payload': 'n/a'} for qr in quick_replies]
requests.post(FB_URL % 'me/messages', json=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()
```

I get the `quick_replies` list from Wit.ai, when it calls my send action. For example:

```
def send(request, response):
    fb.send_message(request['session_id'][32:], response['text'], response['quickreplies'] if ('quickreplies' in response) else None)
    return request['context']
```